# How to write function that returns a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x

Have some problems about the code below line 20.

Question:
The function returns a list of 50 strings that are at
the center of the file.

A file has n lines, then n/2 is the center. A list of length 50 is returned, where the first line is n/2 -25 and the last line is n/2 + 25.

- If the file has n < 50 lines, then only those lines are returned.
- If there are no lines in the file, an empty list object is returned.
- If the file cannot be opened because it does not exist, you must catch the FileNotFoundError object and throw a new exception FileNotFoundError with the contents of the exception being the filename. Any other exception for failure to open a file is not caught.
- If the parameter filename is not a string type, then a TypeError exception is thrown with the contents of the exception being a string "parameter filename is not a string".

Examples:

- the file has 200 lines. lines 75 - 124 are returned
- the file has 201 lines. lines 75 - 124 are returned (n is an odd number)
- the file has 202 lines. lines 76 - 125 are returned
- the file has 700 lines. lines 325 - 374 are returned
- the file has 10 lines. lines 1 - 10 are returned

See appendix for open(), close(), readlines() and isinstance() to support this question.

Restrictions:
Only Allowed: while loops, if statements, function len(), type(), isinstance(), list method append(),
string method split(), format(). keywords elif, else, return, break, continue, def, self, None, try,
raise, except, is, import sys, and any arithmetic or boolean comparison operators

```
def get_first_and_last_24(filename):
    if type(filename)!=str:
        raise TypeError('parameter filename is not a string')
    try:
        f=open(filename)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError(filename)

lines=f.readlines()
len(lines)=length
f.close()
if len(lines)==0:
    return []
n=[]
index=0
while index<len(lines):
    if len(lines)<50:
        n.append(lines[index])
        index+=1            
    elif len(lines)>=50
        if length%2==0:
            if (index/2-25)<index and index < (index/2+25):
                n.append(lines[index])
            index+=1

        elif length%2!=0:
            if ((index-1)/2-25)<index and index<((index-1)/2+25):
                n.append(lines[index])
            index+=1
    return n    
print(get_first_and_last_24('tfre.tx')) 


actual results:
File "3beater.py", line 20
elif len(lines)>=50
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the difference you see between these two `elif`s: 1. `elif len(lines)>=50` 2. `elif length%2!=0:`?

Comment: @Austin the second is executed when first one is True

Comment: You missed a colon in the first one.

Comment: also this is wrong I think: `len(lines)=length`?

Comment: @Netwave what else? the program runs but only print the first line of the given file

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pointing you to look at the validity of your syntax. In this case you are missing a a colon. It should be `elif len(lines)>=50:`